# Is there any way to use HTTP 410 Gone on Google Blogger blogs?

Tags: blogger, 410-gone, blogspot

I want to ask about HTTP 410 Gone if I can use it on Blogger Blogspot. As we know by default the wrong URL returned to 404 Not Found, but I want to remove some old blog posts and I want to return them to HTTP 410 Gone instead of 404 Not Found.

In my template this code is the only one used to handle with Error pages:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;error_page&quot;'>
  <title>
    404: Page Not Found | 
    <data:blog.title/>
  </title>
</b:if>
```

So, any suggestions can help me with this matter?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. If you want full leverage then get a proper hosting platform or wait until Google drops the 404's since the outcome is the same as a 410.

Comment: By default, the error page returned to 404 Not Found only. I'm asking only if there are any codes or anything else can help me control these errors types.

Comment: There isn't any... your not using a real host therefore you should expect limitations as this.

Comment: mmmmm Thank You, I've asked only if there anything I missed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to return a status code 410 from Google Blogger. However you'll notice that a 404 is almost as good as a 410 in most cases, especially if your host has unlimited bandwidth like Blogger.

If you want to specifically notify an end user that the post is gone, you can always use a code snippet in your custom 404 page that checks the current page URL against a list of deleted posts. This will enable you to show a user-friendly message saying that the post was deleted.

I wouldn't recommend using redirects or any other status codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. But instead i would suggest you to use a 301 redirect.

This is a way better solution. All the incredible, big and mighty seo power from your dead page will get redirected to your new page.

Comment: 301 redirect to what?  Presumably if you want to say the content is "Gone" it is because you don't have anything to redirect to.